# Как лучше добавлять в группы пользователей

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Делаю так но на выходе получаю в `groups` пусто

```
groups.forEach(function (groupe) {
    if (typeof groupe != 'array') {
        groupe = [];
    }
    if (groupe.length < 2) {
        groups.push(groupe.push(socket.id));
    }

});
```

Может так нельзя, для тех кто не поймёт чуть допишу до полноты картины

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    groups.forEach(function (groupe) {
        if (typeof groupe != 'array') {
            groupe = [];
        }
        if (groupe.length < 2) {
            groups.push(groupe.push(i));
        }

    });
}
```

Ожидаю получить `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]`

В общем я сделал так но не думаю что это лучший вариант=)

```
        var put = false;
        var find = false;
        groups.forEach(function (groupe, key) {
            var index = groupe.indexOf(socket.id);
            if (index != -1) {
                find = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (!find) {
            groups.forEach(function (groupe, key) {
                if (groupe.length < 2) {
                    groupe.push(socket.id);
                    put = true;
                }
            });
            if (!put)
                groups.push([socket.id]);
        }
```

Вот так потом удаляю из групп, не уверен будет ли работать для групп состоящих из 3-х и более человек, то есть если заменить лимит в группе

```
function ClearGroups(groupes, users) {
    groupes.forEach(function (groupe,key) {
        groupe.forEach(function (user) {
            var index = users.indexOf(user,groupe_key);
            if (index == -1) {
                groupe.splice(groupe_key, 1);
            }
        });
        if(groupe.length == 0){
            groupes.splice(key, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понимаю, в чем состоит задача. Если абстрагироваться от групп и сокетов, что нужно сделать?

Кроме того, отмечу, что `Array.prototype.forEach` нужен для выполнения операций над всеми существующими элементами массива. Для поиска конкретного элемента корректнее использовать **[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**. Если нужно добавить значение в массив, то `forEach` не нужен.

Т.е., например, решая задачку "как разбить список элементов на группы по 2 элемента" (получить `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]`), можно применить такой подход:

```
/**
 * Adding the item to the list. Creates a new array, if there is no one with 
 * enough space in it according to splitLimit.
 *
 * @item
 * @list - 2 dimension array
 */
function addItemToListWithSplitLimit(item, list, splitLimit) {
    var room = list.find(group => group.length < splitLimit) || [];

    room.push(item);
    addObject(list, room);

    return list; // or you could return result of room.push(item)
}

function createItemsListWithLimit(length, limit) {
    var items = getRangeFromZero(length);
    var list = [];
    var add = addItemToListWithSplitLimit;

    return items.reduce((list, item) => add(item, list, limit), list);
}

// Utils

function getRangeFromZero(limit) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(limit)).map((_, i) => i);
}

function addObject(array, object) {
    var isInArray = array.indexOf(object) !== -1;

    return isInArray ? object : array.push(object);
}
```

Создать такой список: `createItemsListWithLimit(10, 2)`

Comment: пытаюсь въехать в код и как то применить его к объектам, туго идёт с утра, то есть по сути в группе будет храниться объект пользователя с каким то именем  , ид, очками и прочей инфой. Но за find  спасибо раньше не использовал его